# Is that correct..while executing 'dbContext.SaveChanges()' command EF compare the local and context value to generating query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image]

after execution of above code noticed..that only *modifiedDate* value is changed in DB and rest are same.

Here is the query generated (capture through SQL server profiler)..

[image]

On behalf of this, can we say that..

Comment: Don't paste pictures of code, its more than a little annoying... Also, if the values you are setting are the same as what's in the entity you pulled back (what's in memory), then it will not try to update those fields. It seems the only thing that's changed (you set differently) is the date

Answer (score 0):

it will not update the value because it is same as it loaded the data. It will only update the value if before retrieval you have changed the value to false.

So if you want to try to see if it works.

```
//manual update db

var selectedData = _context.TableEntity.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userInputId);

if (selectedData != nul)
{
   selectedData.boolean = true;

   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

also a word of advice, you are querying it on a `where` clause `BooleanProperty == true`. I would suggest not updating it as it is already `true`

or if you want you could use, but this will update ALL FIELDS

```
_context.Entity(selectedData).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```